# Как создать кнопку скачки файла?

Tags: html, download

У меня на сайте должен быть файл который надо скачать а как сделать так чтобы оно скачивалось я не знаю. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: тег `a` c атрибутом `href`  http://htmlbook.ru/html/a

Comment: `<a href="path/to/file" download>*</a>`